# Inkscape's textext plugin unable to produce LaTeX symbol

Tags: fonts, svg, inkscape

Typesetting `\[\LaTeX\]` in [textext](https://textext.github.io/textext/) extension/plugin of `InScapes` throws the following error. **Question**: Is something additional that needs to be done here, and/or, are there any workaround to resolve the issue in `textext`? The extension works fine for typesetting, `\[\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\]`, for example.

**Error**

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in display math mode.

@->\spacefactor

@m {}
```

Comment: unrelated to inkscape you would get that error from latex anyway. Why do you want to use `\LaTeX` in math mode?  You could use `\[\mbox{\LaTeX}\]` if you really want that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to inkscape. This latex document gives the error that you show

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\LaTeX\]
\end{document}
```

It is hard to guess why you would ever want the LaTeX logo in math mode and it is not designed to work in math.

If you really want this then switching back to text mode with `\mbox` works

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\mbox{\LaTeX}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly in InkScape extension (thank you) . I thought the issue has to do with InkScape extension. I was wrong. Maybe, I should have tested in my MikTeX installation first so I would have known the issue is not related to InkScape plugin.